# IE8 css dropdown issue hovering not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a css dropdown code which is working fine in all browsers except IE8 quirks mode.
badly stuck with my code please help.i think hover is not working in IE8 quirks mode.
I have little idea about css please guide.

Here is html

```
<UL id=navmenu-h>
   <LI><A href="#">Home</A></LI>
   <LI><A href="#">Paper Rolls </A>
        <UL>
            <LI><A href="#">ATM Rolls </A></LI>
        </UL>
    </LI>
</UL>
```

Here is css

```
UL#navmenu-h {
    Z-INDEX: 1; POSITION: relative; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BACKGROUND: #54b948; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}
UL#navmenu-h UL {
    Z-INDEX: 1; POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 200px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px
}
UL#navmenu-h UL UL {
    Z-INDEX: 1; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 100%
}
UL#navmenu-h UL UL UL {
    Z-INDEX: 1; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 100%
}
UL#navmenu-h LI {
    Z-INDEX: 1; POSITION: relative; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; COLOR: #54b948
}
UL#navmenu-h UL LI {
    Z-INDEX: 1; WIDTH: 100%
}
UL#navmenu-h A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; WIDTH: auto; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; DISPLAY: block; FONT: bold 13px Arial, sans-serif; BACKGROUND: #54b948; FLOAT: left; COLOR: #fff; BORDER-RIGHT: #fff 0px solid; TEXT-DECORATION: none; PADDING-TOP: 6px
}
UL#navmenu-h A:hover {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #f0f0f0; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #f0f0f0; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #f0f0f0; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #f0f0f0
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #f0f0f0; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #f0f0f0; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #f0f0f0; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #f0f0f0
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI A:hover {
    BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover A {
    BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover UL UL {
    DISPLAY: none
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover UL UL UL {
    DISPLAY: none
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover UL UL UL UL {
    DISPLAY: none
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover UL UL UL UL UL {
    DISPLAY: none
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover UL {
    DISPLAY: block
}
UL#navmenu-h UL LI:hover UL {
    Z-INDEX: 1; DISPLAY: block
}
UL#navmenu-h UL UL LI:hover UL {
    Z-INDEX: 1; DISPLAY: block
}
UL#navmenu-h UL UL UL LI:hover UL {
    Z-INDEX: 1; DISPLAY: block
}
UL#navmenu-h UL UL UL UL LI:hover UL {
    Z-INDEX: 1; DISPLAY: block
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 1px solid; FONT: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif; BACKGROUND: #fff; FLOAT: none; COLOR: #656565; BORDER-TOP: 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 1px solid
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 1px solid; FONT: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif; BACKGROUND: #fff; FLOAT: none; COLOR: #656565; BORDER-TOP: 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 1px solid
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 1px solid; FONT: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif; BACKGROUND: #fff; FLOAT: none; COLOR: #656565; BORDER-TOP: 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 1px solid
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 1px solid; FONT: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif; BACKGROUND: #fff; FLOAT: none; COLOR: #656565; BORDER-TOP: 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 1px solid
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI A:hover {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI A:hover {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI A:hover {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
UL#navmenu-h LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover LI:hover A {
    Z-INDEX: 1; BACKGROUND: #54b948; COLOR: #fff
}
.menuColor {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #54b948
}
```

Comment: Why would you want compatibility for quirks mode? I don't understand.

Comment: I didn't read your question but at a glance on your post I saw you have use uppercase letters in HTML tags. Don't do it. always use lowercase letters in your HTML tag. Its good practice.

Comment: our application is used by many users so we don't want the users to change their browser setting every time to access our site

Comment: If their browser is in quirks mode it's because you put it there but you never want to be in quirks mode. Quirks mode's box model is different from strict and that's why you have this problem. Quit putting your user's view in quirks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue.  It turned out I was missing .

Entering the following at the top of my HTML page solved my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score -1):

add position:relative on the div under your menu